# How to create different gallery-types and let the editor choose between them?

Tags: gallery, editor, html-editor

## What I want to achieve

The editor should be able to add galleries via the native wordpress way **and choose between 3 different gallery types**. These 3 types should all have their custom code-output, defined by me. I'd like to go a step further and give the editor **only** the gallery-type to choose from.

I imagine the admin-area add-on really simple, like so:
[image]

Could somebody please walk me through the process of implementing this. Noteform is enough! Specifically:

1. Giving the editor **only** a dropdown to choose the gallery-type
2. Custom output for the different types.

,

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest using custom fields for it. List of good ones:

- https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/
- https://carbonfields.net/docs/

Those custom fields provide you with an option to create a select field and you can display the gallery depending on a type chosen. Please let me know if you need further information.

Comment: Thanks! and yes, I defenitely need further information. A post will surely have more than one gallery. 1) Are the native wp galleries implemented as a custom post type internally, so that the custom field will be applied to the gallery and not the post in your idea? And 2) How can I hook into the gallery editor to show only this one dropdown menu and hide everything else?

Answer (score 0):

I could answer the first question myself. The hook I was looking for is `post_gallery` (https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/post_gallery) – Whenever a gallery shortcode is getting

To consider when using this hook: The original function generating the html for galleries `gallery_shortcode()` (in wp-includes/media.php) returns the new content as soon as the filter `post_gallery` is used somewhere, leaving you alone with quite some work to do if you want to keep the flexibility of the original function. **I highly suggest reading the original function first.**

As for my second question, I still need assistance– I came up with a rather unsatisfied workaround and now use the `columns` input in the gallery-settings panel on the right as my `gallery_type` – Luckily for me the 9 predefined options is exactly the count of types I need.

But for the editor it's quite inconvenient and "hacky" to choose the gallery-type like this..

It's sad, because altering this panel is the only thing left on my wish-list; my `post_gallery` filter is ready for a shortcode like this `[gallery ids='1,4,8' type='7']`